# Character classes used in ffi-aspell

Tags: ruby, regex, dictionary, nlp, aspell

I am trying to use the [ffi-aspell](https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi-aspell/versions/1.1.0) gem to spell check a text. In order to do that, it seems that I have to extract the words by myself. I am trying to do that by applying `String#scan` to the text with a regex, but it does not seem straightforward.

What is the easiest way to define the class of characters that may appear in an ffi-aspell dictionary of some language? I want to make it available not only for English, so things like `/[a-zA-Z']/` for the character (or `/[a-zA-Z']+/` the word) does not work. `/[[:word:]]/` seems to capture characters that are not in the dictionary, such as numerals, and further does not match the apostrophe (single quote), which is frequently used in a word. Is there some documentation that defines the character set used in an ffi-aspell dictionary?

Comment: Would not it be easier to scan `ffi_aspell` _dictionary_ first for entries and just kinda `Regexp#union` uniques afterwards?

Comment: @mudasobwa I think that would give a perfect solution. It would be flexible, and gives the exact set I want. Can you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would be easier to scan `ffi_aspell` *dictionary* first for entries and just kinda `Regexp#union` uniques afterwards.